# ARM development environment for newbies

Tags: arm

I am looking for some information on programming ARM devices, in a particular non-particular way [1]. Assume that I am writing code for an ARM processor that is used a machine similar to a Apple II/Atari  "****" XL/Commodore 64/DOS-PC, or even something that runs a multitasking OS like VMS or SUNOs. Assume further  that any peripherals/OS specific stuff has already been abstracted into subroutines.Examples of this type of programing might be: a text/curses based game like rogue or moria; a curses based word processor ( or rather something based on a curses like library ) ; or a modem/terminal program.

I'm looking for two things. Materials to help learn ARM programming, though the ARM System Developers Guide may be enough, other resources would be helpful I'm looking in particular for something which explains the software ( and relative hardware ie registers ) differences of various generations of processor.

The other thing I'm looking for is a development environment which inculdes, emulation, a decent macro assembler, and a debugger. Along with any thing else that will help me see what is going on inside my programs.

[1] OK. Sorry I just couldn't resist that particular pun.

Comment: http://beagleboard.org/ is a good arm hardware platform with loads of options for software development.

I also found the book "ARM System-on-chip Architecture" by Steve Furber to be quite good when it came out, but it is a bit old now...

Answer (score 2):

You have the choice of using ARM Cortex M or A series. If you are going to develop high end applications such as those which run on smartphones / tablets, then learning about ARM A is your choice. If you are going for an emphasis with hardware/low level stuff such as controllers then you should go for ARM Cortex-M. If you are into real time applications (which I doubt is your case, them use the R series).

Most of these new ARM generations are based on ARMv7 architecture and ISA, so reading the manuals on that could get you started. Most recently, a new ARMv8 architecture and ISA have been announced, it supports 64 bit processing.

Download the reference and technical manuals from ARM site to learn about the HW/peripherals.

I would go with auslen's suggestion of buying a board, you could go with TI's Stellaris Launch pad which has an ARM-M4F processor (supports floating point and SIMD), it sells for 12.99$ 
http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/stellaris_head.html?DCMP=stellaris-launchpad&HQS=stellaris-launchpad-b

or you could go with ST's discovery board (based on the same processor as above), but has audio, accelerometer and usb on board. it sells for 14.99$ http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/252419.jsp
or the STM F3 board (10.99$)
http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/254044.jsp

In any case, you need to check the examples which come with the board, without which you could go nowhere easily. The board comes with its own drivers, all is abstracted in a way, so you could get started from there!

As for OS, if your interest is an RTOS, ARM provides the CMSIS RTOS for it's M series processors
http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php

This book offers an introduction to the generations of ARM processors. Then focuses on cortex M3. It covers its ISA with lots of assembly code. It also addresses the built-in peripherals and how to start-up with C.
http://www.amazon.ca/Definitive-Guide-ARM-Cortex-M3/dp/185617963X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1352506616&sr=8-1

good luck

Answer (score 2):

infocenter.arm.com and look at the various ARM ARMs (architectural reference manuals) and TRM's (technical reference manuals) for the various architectures and cores.  these manuals are better than most other companies documentation.  except for the new 64 bit stuff, the difference from one architecture to the next is somewhat subtle as far as the instruction set goes.  the major differences have to do with the peripherals,  the mmu is a slow changing thing, the interrupt manager has taken big steps and the fpu has been replaced at least once if not twice wholesale (if you even have an fpu which, having one is the exception not the rule it consumes a huge real estate for such little return).

I am confused with your question.  I think it is important to draw the line between learning the architecture/instruction set and learning the operating system calls, these are two separate things.  Operating system stuff you rarely need to look beyond the source code (C/C++), and the limited asm is for hand tuned C libraries or boostrap code, and interrupt wrappers.  Likewise the architecture, registers, instructions, etc vs the peripherals (the cores from arm generally have very very few peripherals, the bulk are in the vendor specific stuff) which I would separate as a separate learning curve, has little to do with asm and the instruction set so no different than learning a peripheral on any other platform, just some addresses you read and write.

If you are looking for non-operating system bare metal the stm32f0 discovery is $10, I highly recommend it.  Looks like ti has a stellaris launchpad for just a little more (waiting for mine to arrive so I cant talk much about them, and shipping is free from ti so the cost is basically the same as the stm32 boards) the stm32f4 discovery is about $20 and I would barely call a microcontroller with all the stuff the cortex-m4 has.

Moving up to linux capable or designed for linux systems there is the raspberry pi, beaglebone and open-rd and on up (pandaboard).  Again though you are just writing just another linux C/C++ program so there isnt much excitement there (related to a specific platform, the entertainment is the same for all platforms) and very little arm knowledge required if any.  It is very easy to use any of these platforms for bare metal programming giving you race car like performance compared to the ARM based microcontrollers.

I have a thumb simulator which you are probably not interested in.  gdb has the armulator which was the cornerstone of the company back in the day.  skyeye or something like that has an arm instruction set simulator as does qemu, none of them will give you great visibility other than what gdb can provide.  opencores has the amber project an armv2 clone, which you can see the close relationship to the armv4 and newer that you will not find rtl for without a box full of cash.  with my arm and chip experience (No I do not work for arm) I do find the amber project worth looking at, but many folks wont know what to do with it and really are not interested in that level of visibility.  (it is instruction compatible, a good design, but dont think you are looking at an arm design, no secrets there).  you can learn the basic arm architecture from it and then move on to hardware for example...

With the microcontrollers being cortex-m based, you might find the older microcontrollers a better stepping stone to the upper end arm cores.  ARM7tdmi based stuff like the sam7s and others from nxp, st, atmel, etc which you can still find at sparkfun and microcontroller pros and other places for arduino like prices.